# Integer Partitions and Divisor Function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I am asked to prove that $$\frac{d}{dt}(\Pi(t)) = \Sigma(t)\Pi(t)$$ and deduce that $$np(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \sigma(n)p(n - k).$$ Here $\Pi(t)$ is the generating function for the partition function $p(n)$.  Further, $\Sigma(t)$ is the generating function for the divisor function $\sigma(n)$, however this generating function is defined as follows $$\Sigma(t) = \sum_{n \geq 1}\sigma(n)t^{n - 1}$$.

Now, so far, I have gotten to this point

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    \frac{d}{dt}\left(\Pi(t)\right) &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{1 - t^n}\right)\\
    &= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{nt^{n - 1}}{(1 - t^n)^2}\left(\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{1 - t^n}\right)\\
    \end{split}
   \end{equation*}

but I am not sure what to do with left hand side.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight error in your derivative computation. We have
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\Pi(t)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nt^{n - 1}}{(1 - t^n)^2}\left( \prod_{\substack{m \geq 1 \\ m \neq n}} \frac{1}{1 - t^m}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nt^{n - 1}}{(1 - t^n)}\prod_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 - t^m} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nt^{n - 1}}{(1 - t^n)} \cdot \Pi(t).$$

Now expand $\frac{1}{1 - t^n}$ as a geometric series to obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nt^{n-1}}{(1 - t^n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nt^{n - 1}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}t^{nm}\right) = \sum_{\substack{n \geq 1 \\ m \geq 0}}nt^{n(m + 1) - 1} = \sum_{n,m \geq 1}nt^{nm - 1}.$$
Collecting together like powers of $t$, we see that
$$\sum_{n,m \geq 1}nt^{nm - 1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma(n)t^{n - 1}$$

Then
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\Pi(t)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma(n)t^{n - 1}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}p(m)t^m = \sum_{\substack{n \geq 1 \\ m \geq 0}}\sigma(n)p(m)t^{n + m - 1}.$$
Collecting like powers of $t$, the right-hand side becomes
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(n)p(n - k)\right) t^{n - 1}$$
Since we also have
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\Pi(t)) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}np(n)t^{n - 1},$$
comparing coefficients shows that
$$np(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(n)p(n - k)$$

Comment: How did you remove the exponent 2 from the denominator in the first line?  I'm not quite sure what strategy you are using there.

Comment: Also, good name haha.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you have done now thank you.